# How to remove file from user's home folder on Nokia N9 (MeeGo) on app removal

Tags: qt, shell, debian, meego

My Qt application for Nokia N9 stores some data in the my folder inside /home/user/.config.
I need to delete this folder with my data when application will be uninstalled.
As far as I understand this can be reached using postrm file.
I use the following file:

postrm

```shell
#!/bin/sh

rm -rf /home/user/.config/mydatafolder/

exit 0
```

But this code doesn't work. I assume there's not enough right to remove something in the user's folder.
So, I've tried to use

```shell
devel-su user -c "rm -rf /home/user/.config/mydatafolder/"
```

But it works only in developer mode and I need the app to work properly without it. The following code doesn't work too:

```shell
su user -c "rm -rf /home/user/.config/mydatafolder/"
```

Does anybody know how to remove this folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've solved this.
You don't need to use su or su-devel in this case. All pre/post rm/install scripts are running by 'root' by default.
To make those scripts running by 'user' we simply need to add following strings to the aegis manifest file:

```xml
<request context="INSTALL">
    <credential name="UID::user" />
    <credential name="GID::users" />
</request>
```